# Random 2D Zombie walking

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, 2d, physics

I need a simple AI script to make a zombie object 'walk' around randomly. I've googled and googled but all I can find is stuff on the mathematics function 'Random Walk'. Maybe it's related?

I'm using my own JavaScript 2D engine and I need to have something like:

```
function update() {
    //Move using available physics engine stuff:
    // this.position, this.rotation, this.velocity, this.torque, this.acceleration
    // this.torqueAcceleration, this.drag, this.torqueDrag
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Use a random function to get a low percentage chance to change the direction (invert the value)? -- Please explain further what you problem is here. -- Something like: `if (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) == 0) // 10% chance
    this.acceleration *=  -1;`

Comment: If you want to have something "truly" random, you have to use `Math.random()`. Mix this with distance, and all your variables. I assume you don't mean AI?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really mean AI (I've already built the AI), that's why I said simple.. Just couldn't think of a better way to phrase it - behaviour would have been better

Comment: Mat Buckland, in his book Programming Game AI by Example, explains a bot behavior he calls Wander. Which makes a bot wander about instead of just walking along a straight path. It's simple enough to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did do a similar script in C# XNA 2 years ago.

The logic is simple. Let's talk about the logic of walking one zombie in pseudo-code:

The following is the walkable space / platform for the zombie:

```
x = 0 ___________________________ x = 100
```

1. Pick a random position to spawn the zombie.
2. If the position is more than half the walkable space, zombie face left. Otherwise zombie face right.

   ```
   x = 0 _____________________<_____ x = 100
   x = 0 _______>___________________ x = 100
   ```
3. Pick a random distance to move between 5 to the end of the walkable space.
4. Start the walking the zombie for the distance picked.
5. Wait for a amount of time between 2 seconds to 15 seconds (15 seconds because some zombies just like to daze around).
6. Go to Step 2

This should help you to create your script for all the zombies to roam around the map aimlessly. You can vary the values I've written in the pseudo-code to suit your game.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you do know this has nothing to do with specific coding at all. This is purely logic. AI (artificial intelligence) logic to be more specific.

Your zombie spawns, what next? You want to assign a behavior. Write down some different behaviors.

- Stand still
- Walk

If the zombie is standing still, do nothing.
If the zombie is walking, pick a random speed and random direction.
Pick a new behavior every x seconds.

What I'd do:

```
// pick behavior between 0 and 5 seconds
var behaviorTimeout = setTimeout(randomBehavior, Math.round(Math.random() * 5000);

function randomBehavior() {
    // set random values
    this.rotation = Math.random() * 360; // assuming its in degrees
    this.velocity = Math.random() * MAX_ZOMBIE_SPEED;

    // run this again in something between 0 and 5 seconds
    behaviorTimeout = setTimeout(randomBehavior, Math.round(Math.random() * 5000);
}
```

This obviously only counts for walking. You'd need another random number deciding if it should walk or stop.

This is the most basic AI logic someone can think of. If you're not talking about zombies anymore, but actual thoughtful creatures understanding and creating AI will get way harder.